# Jacoco reports for unit test and integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jacoco

I am trying to separate unit test from integration tests. I have unit tests in src/test/java and IT in src/integration-test/java.

I will put the pom.xml here:

```
   <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${release.version}-${branch.type}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Integration*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}/src/integration-test/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

I have a profile for integrtion tests:

```
 <profiles>
    <!-- Integration Tests Profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skipUnitTests}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.failsafe-version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/integration-test/java</testSourceDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Integration*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco-maven.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test-coverage-report</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I run mvn test , jacoco-ut.exec is created with unit tests coverage

When I run mvn verify -Pintegration-tests jacoco-it.exec is created but when I check the report with "Show coverage data" from IntelliJ, I have the same unit test classes and not integration-tests classes. An error that I observed in console is :Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file. I tried a lot of solutions but I have the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing I see is that you follow convention over configuration which means your unit tests should be name like `*Test.java` and your integration tests should be named like `*IT.java` also clearly using maven-surefire-plugin for unit test and maven-failsafe-plugin for integration tests and do not use separate directory structure for integration tests keep them separated by naming convention it's easier... also this: `<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${release.version}-${branch.type}</finalName` is not really needed nor does it really makes sense....

Comment: Also you should use maven-failsafe-plugin and correctly attach it to the life cycle phases as described in the documentation (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) and furthermore why separating the exeuction of integration tests via a profile? simply use the life cycle running `mvn package` to run unit tests and use `mvn verify` to run unit tests incl. integration tests.. (Take a deeper look here: https://youtu.be/IVwbrhYCLpc)

Comment: Hi, my goal is to separate unit test from integration tests and to run them separately. I don’t want to run them togheter, that’s why I made a profile and I exlcuded surefire from there. I want to be able to tu IT separately from UT. My unit test classes have Test in name and my IT classes have IntegrationTest in name.

Comment: You can run them separately ... that's not the problem here... as I mentioned use the life cycle (or as you already defines the skip property in surefire the same way in maven-failsafe-plugin; take a look into the YT video)... furthermore you should use the `prepare-agent-integration` and merge the result later together ... to have a combined report if you like to merge the result if not you don't need to do the merge...I've see that you named you test/integration different than the default naming convention...makes it only harder... than it should be...